# How to display images (from the web) in a loop?

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, slideshow

I need images display in my imageview with the time interval of 2 seconds.  But, this code displaying only the last image

```
NSUInteger i,j;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSURL *picUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://panagtakdo.com/misc/images/%d.jpg",i]];
    NSData *picData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:picUrl];
    image1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:picData];
    NSLog(@"Image %d Success",i);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't do it like that. First create NSMutableArray *imageData;

and initWithContentsOfURL all of your images;

when number of imageData equals to your kNumImages the link it to your imageView. Rather then using NSThread sleepForTimeInterval,  you can use performSelector: afterDelay function to change the image.

Answer (score 1):

To just explain, why your code is *NOT* working:

Your thread is sleeping right after setting the image. There is no time to redraw the imageview, (which would result in the display of the new image). So the first redraw will happen, after all loops have been run. So you only see the last image.

If you combine Travis and mhunturk answer's, you have the perfect solution on how it should be done.
But I would also suggest to use asynchronous methods, to load the images from an url.

> You should *never* block the main UI thread. Neither with a direct call of sleepForTimeInterval, nor with loading web-content synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an animated sequence of images, you can create a UIImage that does just that:

```
NSMutableArray *mImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    NSString *imageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d.tiff",i];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFileName];
    [mImageArray addObject:newImage];
}

UIImage *animatedSequence = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:mImageArray duration:16];

UIImageView *uiiv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:animatedSequence];
[self.canvas addSubview:uiiv];
```

You can control the timing of the images by setting the UIImage's duration. I've set the duration to 16s which turns into 2s / image because I have used 8 images in my sequence.

(tested this in the ios simulator and it worked nicely)

P.S. in my project structure, self.canvas refers to the main UIView